# postgresql table updated only by trigger

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible, to configure a Postgres database such, that a specific table may only be updated by a trigger. I have history table, updated by trigger, so I want to prevent this table from un unauthorised access. I want history table to be updated only from trigger.

Comment: The problem is I should grant privileges to operators, To let them change the history data with trigger, but I don't want them to change something directly in history table. they should communicate with history table only using trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Both the history table and the table with the trigger belong to a user that has no login rights. Then you grant privileges on the latter table to the application user.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent unauthorized access to a table you can change the owner of the table to the user who should be accessing with the following query:

```
alter table yourschema.yourtable owner to youruser;
```

Now you can disable the trigger for all other users using the query:

```
alter table yourschema.yourtable disable trigger triggername all;
```

here `all` means that the trigger is disabled for all the users. Now only the owner will be able to use the trigger to update the table.

Comment: In general you should not change the owner of the table, but rather create other users with restricted rights.

Comment: The problem is I should grant privileges to operators, To let them change the history data with trigger, but I don't want them to change something directly in history table. they should communicate with history table only using trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger always fires on the event on it is defined. Thus, if an update trigger is defined for updates, no one can bypass the trigger during an update if the trigger is enabled.

If you have different user groups with different privileges accessing your database, then you should map this about users in the database. For instance you can disallow that a user can disable triggers on a table.